# Problem with square roots and squares

Tags: roots

Suppose we have
$$ x^{2} = (-x)^{2}.$$

I understand that this equation holds because
$$\begin{aligned}
(-x)^{2} & = (-1\cdot x)^{2} \\
& = (-1)^{2} \cdot x^{2} \\
& = x^{2},
\end{aligned}$$
and so $\sqrt{x^{2}} = \sqrt{x^{2}}$ becomes $x = x$ and everything is fine.

But what if we just take the square root first, like so:
$$\sqrt{x^{2}} = \sqrt{(-x)^{2}}.$$
Wouldn't this gives $x = -x$, which is a contradiction?

Comment: No. The answer is not $x=-x$ but $|x|=|-x|$. By definition, $\sqrt{\ }:[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$

Comment: $\sqrt{a}$ where $a$ is a positive real number gives the unique positive real number $b$ such that $b^2=a$.  For instance, $\sqrt{16}=4$ and only $4$.  Here, $\sqrt{~}$ is being used as a function which means that it only has one output.  It is not true that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$ unless we know that $x$ were positive.  Instead $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$

Comment: It seems that I forgot about that part of the definition of square root. Thank you @Andrei and JMoravitz.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, my question has been resolved. Thanks. If someone wishes to submit an answer I'll mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{x}$ denotes the nonnegative square root of $x$, it is not true in general that $\sqrt{x^2}=x$. For instance, if $x=-5$, then
$$
\sqrt{x^2}=\sqrt{25}=5=-x \, .
$$
So sometimes $\sqrt{x^2}$ equals $x$ and sometimes it equals $-x$, depending on the sign of $x$. In general,
$$
\sqrt{x^2} =
\begin{cases}
x \text{ if $x\geq0$} \\
-x \text{ if $x\leq 0$}
\end{cases}
\, .
$$
What makes things confusing is that if $x<0$, then $-x$ is positive.